# Football betting. How can I calculate the stake values for 2 teams to give the same profit whichever team wins taking into account both stakes?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, recreational-mathematics, gambling

I am trying to implement this formula using a spreadsheet (currently Libre Calc) but any mathematical advice will be gratefully accepted.

Let's say, as an example, there are two teams with the following decimal odds to win.
Team A = 2.5
Team B = 3.0

Now for those unfamiliar with decimal odds, taking team A as an example, a bet of 1 pound would give a return of 2.5 pounds, but this includes the stake so the actual profit is only 1.5 pounds.

Now, I can by trial and error work out that if I bet 3 pounds on team A @ 2.5 I will get a return of 7.5 pounds, and if I bet 2.5 pounds on team B @ 3.0, I will also get 7.5 pounds.

This gives me a profit (after deducting the stake) of 4.5 pounds or 5 pounds respectively.

Then, since only one team can win I would make an actual profit of -

Team A - 2 pounds (7.50 return minus original stake 3.0 minus team B stake 2.5)
Team B - 2 pounds (7.50 return minus original stake 2.5 minus team A stake 3.0 pounds)

Is there any formula to allow me to specify Team A odds, Team B odds, and net profit required (in this example 2 pounds) and see the total amount to bet that when applied pro-rata, would give the same profit whichever team wins.

In the above example I would enter Team A = 2.5, Team B = 3.0, and Profit required = 2 pounds, the result would be 5.5 pounds (to be pro rated @ 3 pounds and 2.5 pounds respectively based on the odds).

I thank you all in advance and accept that this may not be possible, I am also aware that a match could result in a draw but I am not concerned with this at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED TO CORRECT A MISTAKE, NOW IT MAKES SENSE**

This is a nice question. You would expect that in real life this is not possible, since otherwise everybody would do it all the time. At the same time your example shows that it *can* be done some of the time, so apparently it depends on the odds. We'll come back to that at the end.

Suppose some-one offers $A$ odds for bets that team A wins and $B$ odds that team B wins. Following your example we first see what happens if we bet $B$ dollars on team A and $A$ dollars on team B.

As in your example we get in return $AB$ dollars if team A wins and $BA = AB$ dollars (i.e. the same amount) if B wins. We payed $A + B$ dollars so our net profit in this scenario is:

$AB - (A + B)$

Now the symmetry, the fact that it doesn't matter who wins as long as *someone* wins, comes from betting $A$ dollars on B and $B$ dollars on A, but this is preserved if we multiply both numbers with some factor $x$:

If we bet $Ax$ dollars on team B and $Bx$ dollars on team A we get, in either scenario $ABx$ dollars after paying $Ax + Bx$ dollars and so our net profit is

$$ABx - (Ax + Bx) = (AB - A - B)x$$

So if we want this net profit to be some given number $P$, we want to solve the equation:

$$(AB - A - B)x = P.$$

The solution to this is:

$$x = \frac{P}{AB - A - B}$$

Note that $A$ (odds of A), $B$ (odds of B) and $P$ (desired profit) are known, only $x$ needs to be computed, and above formula does.

Once you have found $x$ you can place your bets: put $xA$ dollar on team B and $xB$ dollar on team A.

---

**Numerical example:**

suppose someone offers odds of $A = 8$ for team A and odds of $B = 3$ for team B. You want to make $P = 520$ dollars profit

Step 1: compute $x = \frac{P}{AB - A - B} = 520/(24 - 8 - 3) = 40$.

Step 2: bet $Ax = 8*40 = 320$ dollars on team B and $Bx = 3*40 = 120$ dollars on team A. In total you are spending hence $440$ dollars.

If A wins we get $120A = 120*8 = 960$ dollars. Our net profit is $960 - 440 = 520$ as predicted.

If B wins we get $320B = 320*3 = 960$ dollars. Our net profit is $960 - 440 = 520$ as predicted.

---

**Now where's the catch?**

If $A$ and $B$ are really close to one, say $A = 1.10$ and $B = 1.20$ then $x$ turns out negative. In this example we have:

$$AB - A - B = -0.98$$

Which is smaller than $0$. Now if we take $P$ positive we get that $x$ is negative as well and so we should bet a negative amount on both teams in order to make a profit of $P$. But no-one would take this bet!

An alternative is to take $P$ negative as well, then $x$ becomes positive again and we *can* make the bets, but now we know we will be losing money. In fact we know exactly how much money we are gonna lose: we will 'win' the amount $P$ (which is was negative) and so lose the (positive) amount $|P|$.

So for odds close to one the formula will tell you how hopeless the situation is and for odds far away from one it will tell you how to get rich. Of course in both cases we are ignoring the option of a draw.

Comment: Free money would be nice, but that is not the case here since there is always the possibility ot a draw, either no score or score. So it is not a formula to print free money, but simply a way to rationalise one aspect of betting. By allocating a fixed amount and fixed return based on win odds, you can provide a known amount of stake money for other markets in the same match.

Comment: I have a notification of a suggested edit that basically removes my intro para. I am quite happy removing this, but I understood that I should always explain the research I had done so far to make this a good and valued question. Would members prefer that I removed this intro para explaining my research so far? - if so, I am happy to comply.

Comment: Yeah I saw the suggested edit too, but I think the post is fine as is. Well tasted differ, I don't know what other members think

Comment: I suspect, but do not know, that it may only work where both A and B odds are > 2.0. It is certainly possible under these circumstances to arrive at a figure for the total bet, but can it be calculated ?

Comment: Yes like I said in the post: compute $x$ from the odds and desired profit with the formula I provided. Then use this $x$ to compute the amounts to bet on team A (namely $x$ times the odds for B) and the amount to bet on team B (namely $x$ times the odds for A)

Comment: I added an example in the text

Comment: I like your reasoning and am exploring it. Regards both odds being close to 1 this never happens. In reality team A and team B odds usually total 4 or more, since as one decreases the othe increases. And anyway I would ignore such a match. As an aside, Ive obviously upset someone, maybe by querying the edit cos I got a downvote - Egos eh, who needs em except the insecure :-)

Comment: Ive tried your figures / formulas - excellent. Haven't explored fully but this is enough to prove one example and an excellent starting point for expansion / development. Thank you SO MUCH - awesomwe